# How to add overlay while video is being played and user touch add overlay in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, overlay, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to add overlay on video i have seen the sample for [adding overlay on video](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos). but i don't want to do like this. I mean my video will be running and on this particular video If user will touch any thing than on that thing one overlay will appear and if user touches and moved than the overlay will continuously will be added on that video means user will track that frame. And the video will be saved with this overlay..

is this possible?